# Error message while editing comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

On trying to edit a comment after the 5 minute grace period, I get an error message of the form `Error editing  comment : write_failed`. <s>I wasn't able to get a screenshot as it was visible for only a few seconds.</s>

This should be replaced with the a proper pop-up stating "Comments cannot be edited after 5 minutes of posting" like in the case of the full site.

Version : 0.1.18

**Update**

Here is a screenshot of the error message. I'm on version 0.1.31

[image: Error message write_failed]

Comment: I can't seem to edit comments at all. Not even my own, within the time limit.

Comment: Did it say 'Error editing comment: write_failed'? I've gotten that message and have a screenshot which I can try to add to your post if you would like? I'm on v0.1.31

Comment: @brian yes, that's the error message. Sure, go ahead.

Comment: [Don't offer the "edit" option for comments after the 5 minute window in the android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196291)