# Don't offer the "edit" option for comments after the 5 minute window in the android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, edits, android-app

The Android app shouldn't offer the "edit" option for comments after the 5 minute window.

Currently, the app will give you the menu, allow you to click through and edit it, only to give you a "write_failed" error after submitting. For non-mods, who have a five-minute edit window, it makes no sense to offer the option in the first place.

**Edit:**
Additionally, if you try to discard the edit, the app crashes.

**Update:** [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah I explicitly fixed this because I saw this report and forgot to tell anyone. Fixed as of a month ago or so.